# Count of different string format in a column

Tags: sql

I’ve a column in a table containing data with different date formats like
Column

```
01-02-1999
02032000
04/05/2007
03-02-1997
```

Is there any way to get the count on the basis of string format like below

```
Count (date format1)
Count (date format2)
```

Comment: What's the expected result for that input?

Comment: End goal is to convert the all data in column in single format like ‘01-02-1999’

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: 1. Is there a large number of different formats or, just a few ( less than 10)?
2. How do you know 03-02-1997 means February 3rd or March 2nd

Comment: Is `02032000` midnight on the 20th march 1902? 8pm on the third of Feb?

Comment: @Srinika there are large number of different formats

Comment: I feel like hard to give a DB only solution. There should be something like a machine learning kind of an algorithm in which each format found has to be excluded, and checked with a created Regular Expression

Comment: @Srinika if a human can't decide, you're screwed for getting a compouter to decide!

Comment: @Caius Jard, I meant to say, if the dd,mm,yy positions are to be ignored. More over, with the number of occurrences (guessing) it would be possible to create a system to find which format is it.
ex. if the last 4 digits in a format like 02032000 is larger than 1900, for a very large number of records and the first 2 didn't exceed 12 for a larger number, then that can be determined as mmddyyyy - Anyway no other choice in some of the formats.

Comment: Actually dates are in free format. We received it in a file where no proper sequence has been followed

Answer (score 1):

> End goal is to convert the all data in column in single format like ‘01-02-1999’

SQLServer:

```
STUFF(STUFF(REPLACE(REPLACE(date, '-', ''), '/', ''), 5, 0, '-'), 3, 0, '-')
```

I know, you're going to say "but what if it's not in ddmmyyyy?"

And I say "yes indeed.. what if it's not?"

I figure you or I can't tell the difference, not from the info given at least, so there is little point in getting too artifically intelligent about it; absent any other pointers, it probably doesn't matter whether 02/03/2010 is 3rd Feb or 2nd March.. And all we've actually done is regularize the presentation of the dates. The problem of whether it's dd-mm-yyyy or mm-dd-yyyy remains (and

If it had mattered to the person who wrote this system, they'd have probably used a proper datetime datatype.. If it matters to you know and you can't decide from this data alone, try and draw inference from another date somewhere else like if, for the account opened in 02-03-2000, the first transaction was 25/2/2000 (must be dd/mm/yyyy) then the account date is probably mm-dd-yyyy, because an account that opened on 2nd mar wouldn't be transacting on 25th feb..

:/